# findViewById returns null in fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, findviewbyid

- The `findViewById()` returns `null` in fragment class. The `Toast` for the `ImageButton` shows something but the object for `Switch` i.e. `mySwitch` returns `null`... please help....

  ```
  public MyAdapter(Context context, List<ListItems> values) {

      super(context, R.layout.list_item, values);
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      View v = convertView;
      LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

      if( v == null){
          v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
      }

      ListItems currLoc = LocationList.get(position);

      TextView theTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_textview);
      theTextView.setText(currLoc.getLocation());

      TextView theTextView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_textviewP);
      theTextView2.setText(currLoc.getProfile());

      ImageView theImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "image view="+theImageView, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      theImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bullet);


      Switch mySwitch=(Switch) v.findViewById(R.id.onoff);
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+mySwitch, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


      return v;
  }
  ```

Comment: Please Show xml here

Comment: And the error please. And it's not your `fragment class`, it's your `adapter` Class that

Comment: replace `LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());` by `LayoutInflater inflater = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));`

Comment: **Wild guess**: you're referencing the ListView items from the Fragment, directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.... 
I had defined the findViewById in onGetView
I had to declare it on OnCreateView
Sorry.....

Comment: Fellow reviewers: this _is_ an answer. It's the OP explaining what caused the problem.

Comment: I thought **onCreateView** just returns the layout.  I didn't know you actually call `findViewById` inside of it.